# How do I send a random line from one file?

Tags: python, selenium

How do I send a random line from one file?

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
                   lines = f.readlines()
                   for line in lines:
                       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a random number up to the number of lines, and send the line at that index:

```
import random
with open('names.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    i = random.randrange(len(lines))
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(lines[i])
```